# SlickGrid - Frozen totals row on top

Tags: jquery, sticky, slickgrid

I'm using [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid), and I was wondering if there's a way for me to create a totals row on top, under the header row.

I saw that the issue was brought up here: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/26

And it was implemented here: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/19624f6687a0d2671639c4b1f2c05eb20c9ab0c7. (But I can't find those methods in the current version anymore!)

Also, I found a fork on this site: https://railadvisor.com/js/slickgrid/examples/example15-fork-feature-demo.html.

Could anybody tell me how to do something similar to that using the current implementation of SlickGrid? Also, I wouldn't want the totals row to be filtered. Thanks!

**Edit:** Here's my attempt in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crystality/Jwc6q/ 
(I copied code from these examples: [Multi-column sorting](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-multi-column-sort.html) and [Using fixed header row for quick filters](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. All you have to do now is to calculate totals for each column and append it to the `<p>` (instead of the TOTAL). Also, you can subscribe to the `grid.onCellChange` event to update your header if your table is editable.

Comment: Thanks! At the bottom of my code, I had something that says `val(3)` (copied that from one of the examples). Can you explain that line to me? I'm not sure what it's doing.

Comment: I think you picked this up from one of your examples. The `.val(3)` is setting the value of I am guessing a input element (like a textbox) to 3. In your case, you can use `.text(3)` instead to set the text of your `<p>` element.